# Minitoc with hyperref and \sectounter{section}{0} leads to wrong section

Tags: hyperref, minitoc

I have the following issue with `minitoc`:

I have a first numbered chapter with sections 1 and 2 and a second unnumbered chapter with sections 1 and 2 (sections reset with `\setcounter{section}{0}`). As the second chapter is unnumbered if I do not reset the section number, they are numbered 3 and 4 which is not what I want.

When I generate the minitoc they generate correctly but the hyperlinks are wrong: clicking on the minitoc of the unnumbered chapter leads to the corresponding section of the previous numbered chapter.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Here is a minimimum working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\dominitoc
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\minitoc
\section{a}
\section{b}

\chapter*{foo foo}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\addstarredchapter{foo foo}
\markboth{foo foo}{}
\minitoc

\section{c}
\section{d}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add something like this to your preamble `\renewcommand\theHsection{\thesection.\thepage}`. Without it you will see warnings in the log about targets being duplicates. In short `hyperref` does not like it when there are two sections with the same number. The suggestion above then makes the section counter (seen from `hyperref` a bit more unique)

Comment: Thanks, this solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

In general `hyperref` assumes that all sections have distinct numbers. So when you have two sections numbered `1.1`, `hyperref` complains in the log:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the sa
me identifier (name{section.1.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.22 \section{c}
```

one solution here is to define an internal `hyperref` counter representation which is always unique.

Here you can probably use

```
\renewcommand\theHsection{\thesection.\thepage}
```

provided you never have two setions with the same number on the same page.